# iOS 6 Getting Directions in new Apple Map on Foot or Walking

Tags: ios, ios6, ios6-maps, map-directions

I'm unable get the Walking directions using Apple Map app, But if use **MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving** rather than **MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking** the code works, can someone please help a bit getting on Walking directions?

*I have following code for getting directions, which is working for Driving case...*

```
MKPlacemark* place = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:_targetLocation addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem* destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:place];
destination.name = [lastParkingInfo streetAddress];
NSArray* items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: destination, nil];
NSDictionary* options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey, nil];
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:items launchOptions:options];
```

Comment: Do you get any errors, warnings etc...?

Comment: NO errors or Warning in my code, but Apple Map App display alert like "Could not found directions between these locations"

Comment: Have you tried doing it manually yourself in Maps? It may be a genuine case that it can't figure out pedestrian directions due to the road layout.

Comment: Yes I did tried manually and it works. But doesn't when Maps App is invoked from My App, fails every time.

Comment: use the google map for direction there are a no. of code available for route.